# php Div autoreload without reload the page

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, ajax

I have a ShoutCast and don't work this code :

```js
<script>
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
(function () {
    $("#titles").load("WhatIs.php"); //Load the content into the div
}), 1000);
</script>
```

"WhatIs" is the code that get the title of the song that I'm listening now, "titles" is the Div that I want to put the title.
I want to reload the code every second.

Comment: Have you tried `header("Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8");`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check if your JS is valid without load. If everything is okay then your problem is on your php side : you can replace .load by .ajax to have more debugging functions. Are you sure your php side is correct ?

```js
var test = true ;

var auto_refresh = setInterval(
(function () {
  
  if ( test )
  {
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getTime();
    $('#titles').html(n) ;
    return ;
  }
  
  var ajax = jQuery.ajax({
    'url' : './WhatIs.php' //Load the content into the div
  }) ;
  
  ajax.done(function(data){
    console.log('ajax done',data) ;
    jQuery('#titles').html(data) ;
  }) ;
  
  ajax.fail(function(data){
    console.log('ajax fail',data) ;
    alert(data) ;
  }) ;
  
}), 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="titles"></h1>
```